# query TCP buffer sizes for a socket on linux

Tags: tcp, linux-networking

Is there any way to lookup the send/receive buffer sizes for TCP sockets?

I've poked around with both netstat and ss, as well as the raw /proc/net/tcp. Lots of goodies there, including the counts of bytes in flight, timers, process name, etc.

But I'd like to be able to diagnose whether some proceses are setting SO_{SND,RCV}BUF...and more interestingly what values the kernel is actually using for each SKB.

Comment: Are you looking for the configuration settings (min/max/default), or the current amount of memory used?

Answer (score 6):

From the [lsof FAQ](http://ftp.tuwien.ac.at/utils/admin-tools/lsof/FAQ) (search for "Why doesn't lsof report socket options"), I believe Linux doesn't make the info you're after available. (at least not via /proc)

If it did, you could use `lsof -i <pid> -a -i tcp -T f`, but -T only takes "qs", not f on Linux.  You can get some other info from netstat (`netstat --tcp -p -o -e -e -v | grep <pid>`) which includes the Send Queue and Receive Queue and some timer info.

What you could do is use strace.  You'd have to either run the program via strace (`strace -ff -e network,ioctl PROGRAM`) or before it sets up the TCP socket (`strace -fff -e network,ioctl -p PID`).  `ioctl` is how those options would be set, and `network` should catch enough to tell what connections those are. (but just ioctl and then use lsof to figure out where the connections to should work, too)

Comment: this post is old, but Now in Linux, you can use too lsof -T qs, to the socket buff, I tried on debian jessie and it works

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do that using `https://github.com/veithen/knetstat`.

E.g. for `nc -I 8192 -O 8192 www.google.com 80` this would give (see the `SO_RCVBUF` and `SO_SNDBUF` on the third row):

```
$ cat /proc/net/tcpstat
Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         Stat Diag Options
     0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LSTN      SO_REUSEADDR=1,SO_REUSEPORT=0,SO_KEEPALIVE=0,TCP_NODELAY=0
     0      0 10.132.0.4:22           74.125.73.164:38922     ESTB      SO_REUSEADDR=1,SO_REUSEPORT=0,SO_KEEPALIVE=1,TCP_NODELAY=1
     0      0 10.132.0.4:44058        74.125.206.103:80       ESTB      SO_REUSEADDR=0,SO_REUSEPORT=0,SO_KEEPALIVE=0,SO_RCVBUF=8192,SO_SNDBUF=8192,TCP_NODELAY=0
     0      0 10.132.0.4:44054        74.125.206.103:80       TIMW 
     0      0 10.132.0.4:22           74.125.73.96:45722      ESTB      SO_REUSEADDR=1,SO_REUSEPORT=0,SO_KEEPALIVE=1,TCP_NODELAY=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of the receive and the send buffer as follows (send buffer shown):

```
int buffersize = 64*1024;  // 64k
setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *) &buffersize, sizeof(buffersize));
```

and to get the current size, use:

```
socklen_t buffersize_len = sizeof(buffersize); // in/out parameter
getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char *) &buffersize, &buffersize_len);
```

There is a known bug in Linux that reports the current buffer size as 1/2 the set value.  I can't remember if the internal value is 1/2 of what was requested, or whether the report is 1/2 of what it really is.